# Convert full file path into multiple rows of parents absolute path in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In PySpark data frame, I want to convert a string full file path into multiple rows of each parent path.

**Input dataframe value:**

```
ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/TestFile.txt
```

**Output :**   Every row should display an absolute path along with `/` delimiter

```
ParentFolder/
ParentFolder/Folder1/
ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/
ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/
ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/
ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/TestFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the column `value` by `/` delimiter to get all the parts of the path. Then using [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) function on the split result, you construct the different parent paths using [`slice`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#slice) and [`array_join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#array_join) functions:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn("value", F.split(F.col("value"), "/")) \
    .selectExpr("""
      explode(
           transform(value, 
                     (x, i) -> struct(i+1 as rn, array_join(slice(value, 1, i+1), '/') ||
                                      IF(i+1 < size(value), '/', '') as path)
                     )
       ) as paths
    """).select("paths.*")


df1.show(truncate=False)

#+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
#|rn |path                                                     |
#+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
#|1  |ParentFolder/                                            |
#|2  |ParentFolder/Folder1/                                    |
#|3  |ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/                            |
#|4  |ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/                    |
#|5  |ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/            |
#|6  |ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/TestFile.txt|
#+---+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

For **Spark < 2.4**, you can use UDF like this:

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType


def get_all_paths(path: str):
    paths = [path]
    for _ in range(path.count("/")):
        path, base = os.path.split(path)
        paths.append(path + "/")

    return list(reversed(paths))


decompose_path = F.udf(get_all_paths, ArrayType(StringType()))

df1 = df.select(F.explode(decompose_path(F.col("value"))).alias("paths"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring_index` as below:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr("""
    explode(
        transform(
            sequence(1, size(split(col, '/'))),
            (x, i) -> case when i = size(split(col, '/')) - 1
                           then col
                           else substring_index(col, '/', x) || '/'
                           end
        )
    ) as col
""")

df2.show(20,0)
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|ParentFolder/                                            |
|ParentFolder/Folder1/                                    |
|ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/                            |
|ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/                    |
|ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/            |
|ParentFolder/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/TestFile.txt|
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. just one additional question. can we add row number ( for given group partition)